# Is a double popularity contest a bad idea?

Tags: discussion, challenges

I have an Idea for a set of four challenges. The first round is a double popularity contest. Specifically two questions each linking each other with identical requirements but different judging requirements. Each answer should be posted to both contests but should score differently in each. Specifically in this case one will be the silliest answer, and the other will be the most impressive answer.

Just to note the second round would be a set of golfs where the winning answers from the first round would be golfed. Also the theme would be a polyglot generator.

Comment: Since you ultimately can't control how people vote, I'm not sure these challenges would actually be all that different. Especially people who visit the challenge from other sites might not even read the challenge in full and just scroll through the answers to upvote things they like (and those votes can easily outweigh those from members of the community).

Comment: Even people who fully understand the intended winning criteria may not follow them. If someone really likes an answer and wants it to win, they have an incentive to also go and find it in the other challenge and up vote there rather than voting "honestly".

Comment: I don't think the problem is with having two different criterion, but actually with the "silliest" answer.  People here upvote based on how impressive/interesting the answer is.  Good popularity contests are ones where naturally upvoted answers are the ones they are looking for.  (However, because we generally vote the same way, you end up only having 1 popularity contest, not 2)

Answer (score 14):

No, it will never work. You can't force people to vote a certain way, so one challenge would be a duplicate of the other.

Comment: Not force, but still can advise

Answer (score -1):

I'd propose you maybe have users leave a "+1" comment to vote for sillyness, and leave a regular upvote for impressiveness. That way it's all contained in one question.

I guess users below 50 rep would be excluded though (not that it's a big deal).

This might also need to be a time-limited contest too as nobody is going to want to count "+1" comments after the contest ends... The alternative would be to have one comment on each question that says "+1" and have people vote for that?

Comment: Although I think "silliness" and "impressiveness" are not suitable criteria for a challenge on PPCG, if there were two other (more suitable) criteria then having a comment for each would be a way of counting votes, and then votes on the answer itself would indicate a well written answer (separately from the winning criteria). However, there is still no way to tell whether people actually voted on the criteria they claim. "I like this answer - I'll just upvote all three ways." I think this will have all the difficulties of a standard popularity contest, but magnified.